# Correct U+23F4 and U+23F5 unicode characters?

Tags: linux, unicode

My notebook is a Debian GNU/Linux testing/unstable (stretch), and it is almost up to date.

Both Chrome (version 56) and Firefox (version 45.7 ESR and version 52) show the unicode characters in the pages below pointing to the opposite direction than their names:

[BLACK MEDIUM **LEFT**-POINTING TRIANGLE](https://codepoints.net/U+23F4)

[BLACK MEDIUM **RIGHT**-POINTING TRIANGLE](https://codepoints.net/U+23F5)

In particular, here you can see what's being displayed on my screen for the first:

[image: LEFT pointing on my screen]

and for the second

[image: RIGHT poining on my screen]

EDIT:

After the first answer, I tried changing the font-family value in the inspector. I tried with "Helvetica", "Times", "Arial", "Sans", "Monospace", "Courier" and "Serif".
Some of them differ a bit in how the arrow is drawn (mainly the margins), but all of them draw it in the wrong direction.

I even tried changing the system fonts in the Chrome settings, the defaults were "Times New Roman", "Times New Roman", "Arial", "Monospace". I changed them to "Bitstream Vera Serif", "Bitstream Vera Serif", "Bitstream Vera Sans", "Andale Mono". Still the right arrow points backwards. I suspect it's not a messed up font problem.

EDIT2:

Now I've tried in Libreoffice Writer too. No matter what font I choose, the arrows always point in the wrong direction. I think this is a strong indication it's not a font problem.

EDIT3:

As of June 2020, I'm running the same system, meanwhile updated to Debian Bullseye (testing) and I still see the problem.

Comment: you've got a buggy font somewhere.  those webpages and the glyphs display as described for me on firefox (52) and in urxvt (on arch linux).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the font used in the webpage. For some reason they messed up the symbols in the font.

To test it in Chrome press <kbd>F12</kbd>. It will open the developer tools.

In the right side under *Elements* you can click the element `<body>` for example, and in the right side you can **set** or **remove** the checks on the CSS attributes. Play with it to remove the font-family and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, but see my edits